# Ошибка при qsort по вектору структур

Tags: c++, struct, qsort

Добрый день. Имеется структура:

```
struct part
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int number;
};
```

Из неё формируется не пустой вектор:

```
std::vector<part> arr(n);
```

Вызывается *qsort* для сортировки по полю number:

```
qsort(&arr, arr.size(), sizeof(part), comp);
```

Используя следующий компаратор:

```
int comp( const void* a, const void* b )
{
    return ((part*)a)->number - ((part*)b)->number;
}
```

Как мне подсказал гугл компаратор правильный, но из раза в раз я получаю SIGSEGV. Помогите понять в чём ошибка, мб оно ещё кому поможет.
Без сортировки всё работает. При включении в код сортировки в отладчике массив обозначается *недоступным* после неё.

Полный код:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Rank
{
public:
    static std::string nthRank(const std::string st, std::vector<int> we, int n);
};

struct part
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int number;
};

int comp( const void* a, const void* b )
{
    return (    ((part*)a)->number - ((part*)b)->number   );
}

std::string Rank::nthRank(const std::string st, std::vector<int> we, int n)
{
    if(st.empty()) return "No participants";
    if(we.size()<(unsigned)n) return "Not enough participants";

    std::vector<part> arr(we.size());
    unsigned int com = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < st.size() ; i++)
    {
          if(st[i]!=',')
          {
              arr[com].number +=  std::tolower(st[i])-96 + 1; //1 for length1
              arr[com].name += st[i];
          }
          else
          {
              arr[com].number *= we [com];
              ++com;
          }
    }
    qsort(&arr, arr.size(), sizeof(part), comp);
    return arr[n].name;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string me("COLIN,AMANDBA,AMANDAB,CAROL,PauL,JOSEPH");
    std::vector<int> arr={1, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1};
    me=Rank::nthRank(me, arr, 4);
}
```

Класс Rank - часть задания.

Comment: Приведение unsigned к int положения дел тоже не меняет

Comment: полный компилируемый пример для воспроизведения приведите. + почему `qsort`, не `std::sort`?

Comment: @GreenDragon на второй вопрос: до этого основным языком был Си, от него и осталось

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) — применима только для сортировки Си-массивов (вида `strucr part foo [100]`).
Для сортировки STL-контейнеров, в том числе и векторов используется [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). На практике во всех распространённых реализациях это тот же `qsort()`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool comp( const part & a, const part b )
{
    return a.number < b.number;
}

int main () {
    // ...
    std::vector<part> arr(n);

    // В классическом С++ стиле
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), comp);
    // В C++11 стиле с лямдой
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), 
            [](const part &a, const part &b) { return a.number < b.number; });
    // ...
}
```

---

Вообще говоря, если элементами вектора являются объекты [POD-типа](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) ([тривиального типа](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType) в терминологии С++11), то для сортировки оного формально можно использовать и `qsort()`, однако это крайне некрасиво и при последующем внесении изменений в код чревато ошибками.

```
struct part
{
    //! При замене на std::string с точки зрения стандарта в qsort () будет UB!
    char name[32];
    unsigned number;
};

int comp( const void* a, const void* b )
{
    const unsigned anum=((part*)a)->number, bnum=((part*)b)->number;
    return anum>bnum ? 1 : (anum == bnum ? 0 : -1);
}

// ...
std::vector<part> arr;
// ...
// Не надо так делать! Даже если формально ошибки нет.
qsort(&arr[0], arr.size(), sizeof(part), comp);
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз хотел компаратор лямбдой написать, но всё же интересно, почему не работает qsort()?

Comment: qsort() применима **только** для сортировки Си-массивов.

Comment: qsort может работать и с плюсовыми классами. Главное, что бы они были POD типами (такими, которые можно безопасно копировать с помощью memcpy). Почему так? просто нужно посмотртеть на [сорци](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-344/bsd/kern/qsort.c) (в данном случае это от Эпла, но сути не меняет). Если в структуре есть std::string, то она уже не POD, хотя, из-за SSO, иногда может все работать как ожидается.

Comment: @KoVadim правда, не могу найти причин, почему для pod'ов в векторе нельзя было бы использовать, но ни как не могу отделаться от ощущения, что как-то это очень грязно....

Comment: потому что есть std::sort, который знает, что он работает с с++ объектами. А qsort - нет. Ему только размер и кол-во важно

Comment: добавил вариант с qsort'ом в ответ...

Comment: В "варианте с qsort'ом" сохраняется исходная ошибка в компараторе... По-прежнему вычитание беззнаковых.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо; fixed

Comment: @Fat-Zer Этот компаратор по-прежнему не будет работать правильно, если при выполнении вычитания возникнет переполнение.

Comment: @AnT, если номера положительные, то очевидно нет... но ладно, поправлю т. к. всё же учебный пример.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим следующий [пример (1)](https://ideone.com/RYmdkz) кода:

```
vector<int> vect = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
auto pvect       = &vect;
auto pvect0      = &vect[0];

*pvect0 = 42;
cout << vect[0] << endl;

cout << pvect    << endl;
cout << pvect0   << endl;

cout << sizeof(vect)              << endl;
cout << sizeof(int) * vect.size() << endl;
```

Одним из возможных выводов данной программы будет следующий:

```
42
0x7ffc9d7aa3c0
0x5624574c0c20
24
40
```

Можно заметить, что адрес объекта `vect` не совпадает с адресом первого элемента вектора `vect`. Также размер в байтах объекта `vect` не совпадает с размером в байтах элемента вектора `vect`, умноженного на количество элементов в векторе `vect`.

Данные различия обусловлены тем, что элементы вектора `vect` **хранятся отдельно** от объекта `vect`. Обычно внутри объекта `vect` находится указатель на область памяти, в которой собственно и хранятся его элементы.

Это первая причина, по которой не работает `qsort`. Здесь:

```
qsort(&arr, arr.size(), sizeof(part), comp);
```

вы передаёте `qsort` вовсе не адрес первого элемента вектора `arr`, а адрес объекта `arr`.

Отдельное хранение элементов контейнера свойственно не только для `vector` но и для `string` тоже.

Такая архитектура классов `vector` и `string` обычно означает, что нельзя просто так взять и побайтово скопировать один экземпляр класса в другой. То есть, в терминах стандарта языка классы `vector` и `string` не являются тривиальными типами (trivial types). Подробнее о тривиальных типах: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType. Небольшой [пример (2)](https://ideone.com/q7vmdC).

В стандарте языка явно оговорено (n4659 28.8/3), что поведение программы не определено, если при помощи функции `qsort` пытаются отсортировать массив, элементы которого не тривиального типа.

> The behavior is undefined unless the objects in the array pointed to by `base` are of *trivial type*.

Answer (score 2):

> Как мне подсказал гугл компаратор правильный

В дополнение к вышесказанному можно заметить, что компаратор у вас совершенно НЕ правильный. Так как поле `number` имеет тип `unsigned int`, вычитание `((part*)a)->number - ((part*)b)->number;` будет проводится в домене беззнакового типа и давать беззнаковый результат. Т.е. никакого компаратора у вас так не получится.

(Последующее запихивание результата такого вычитания в тип `int` может "спасти" ситуацию, приведя результат к требуемому виду, но, во-первых, языком это не гарантируется и, во-вторых, при достаточно большой разнице между сравниваемыми значениями все равно будет давать белиберду.)

Бросьте дурную манеру писать компараторы через вычитание, что бы вам там ни говорил Гугл. Универсальная идиома для написания типонезависимых "трехзначных" компараторов, если вам такой вдруг понадобится, выглядит так

```
int comp( const void* a, const void* b )
{
  const part 
    *pa = static_cast<const part *>(a),
    *pb = static_cast<const part *>(b);
  return (pa->number > pb->number) - (pa->number < pb->number);
}
```